# Convert varchar string to Currency format in db2 SQL

Tags: string, db2, currency-formatting

I have a column from which i have to extract String and then format it back to US currency format with 2 decimal places.

**For example :**
Column value : `{tag}0000020000890|`

From this, I have to match the tag and extract 20000890, and format it to 200,008.90

I have extracted the part with below code:

```
LTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('match pattern', 1,1,'i',,1), '0')
```

Where match pattern is `'\{tag\}(.*?)\|'`

With this, I am able to extract  `20000890`

And then I tried the below to_char and to_number function on top of it to format as comma separated currency with 2 decimal points.

```
to_char(ltrim(Regexp_substr('match pattern',1,1,'i',1),'0'), '99G999G999D99')
```

But this throws below error:

> Sql error -20447, sqlstate 22007 sqlerrmc 99G999G999D99
>   Sysibm.Varchar-format

Then I tried,

```
to_char(to_number(ltrim(Regexp_substr('match pattern',1,1,'i',1),'0')), '99G999G999D99')
```

But this also throws error:

> Sql error -20476, sqlstate 22018 sqlermc DECFLOAT_FORMAT; 99G999G999D99

I'm not sure what causes this error.

Comment: Those are not Oracle errors. Are you sure you're not using DB2?

Comment: oops, yes it is DB2 sql Error. I didn;t know that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format that you try to use is supported starting from V11.5 only.
[TO_CHAR V11.5](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html)
[TO_CHAR V11.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html)
Compare the `Table 2. Format elements for decimal floating-point to varchar` table from both links.

Moreover, you must cast a string to a numeric value in the 1-st parameter of `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DECFLOAT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(V, '\{tag\}(.*?)\|', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), '99,999,999.99') 
FROM (VALUES '{tag}0000020000890|') T(V);
```

Comment: cool Thanks, now it works without throwing error but the issue again is, it adds .00 to end but i want last two digits to be taken as decimal parts
Is there any way where i could insert **"."** from right after 2 characters

something like : **Insert(string, ".",right(2)**

Comment: I used regex_replace function and decimal formatted the string inside itself like this
**REGEXP_REPLACE(MESSAGE_TEXT,'.*\{tag\}(.*)(?=\d{2})(\d{2})\|.*','\1.\2')**
and after that applied DECFLOAT and TO_CHAR like you mentioned...It works awesome now ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [VARCHAR_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html). It is the function TO_CHAR is mapped to. The group separator is not G, but "," or ".". Basically, you have to replace your formatting string `99G999G999D99` with something like `99,999,999.99`.

The Db2 documentation has more examples on that.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason varchar_format was throwing error